# How to render items with different views in Yii2 ListView?

Tags: php, listview, yii2

I need to display the news with different views. Now I use this code for a presentation:

```
 <?= ListView::widget([
                   'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                   'itemView' => '_news',
                   'viewParams' => [
                       'fullView' => true,
                       'context' => 'main-page'
                   ]
               ]);
                ?>
```

My problem is this: The first 3 news show with large images, the other display with small images. Pagination should work necessarily. See this example
[image]

Please, help me.

Answer (score 2):

Each item view of List view has a variable called `$index` which can be used to achieve your desired result. In **_news.php** you can do the following,

```
if($index < 3)
    $this->render('_news_big', ['model' => $model]);

else
    $this->render('_news_small', ['model' => $model]);
```

And have the actual code for the big blocks in **_news_big.php** and the code for small blocks in **_news_small.php**.

The other way of doing it is to place the code for both the blocks inside **_news.php**, (although i don't prefer this method)

```
if($index < 3)
{
    //Code for big block
}
else
{
    //Code for small blocks
}
```

For more information about itemView, please refer http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-listview.html#$itemView-detail